# Provability success or fail

Tags: php

I want to make a script in PHP which will determine whether I failed or succeeded by a probability. For example, returning `true` (or "success") 90% of the time, and `false` or "fail" for the other 10%. Basically, there is 9/10 probability that I succeeded, and 1/10 that I failed.

I was trying to use the `rand()` function, to see if the numbers match, but the probabilities for that are too low. I would appreciate if you guys can help me get one or start on one. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$rand = rand(1,100);
$probability = 90;

$succeed = $rand <= $probability;
```

Comment: this will technically give you 1/100 chances.

Comment: hum, I use "<=" , not "=". Don't I get 90/100 chances that $rand is smaller or equal than 90 ?

Comment: @Eduardop911 F.C. is correct. http://codepad.org/1XMHKim0

Comment: oh ok thanks let me give it a try

Answer (score 0):

This is extremely simplified, but perhaps this helps you...

```
// Array with 9 S's and one F -> 90% change of getting an S.
$a = array('S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'F');

echo $a[array_rand($a)];
```

Comment: ok but how would i get it from a 90 to the array? would i do a loop to insert as many F's as necessary

Answer (score 0):

Here's another version based on F.C.'s answer.

This tests probability 10000 times and gives roughly 10 percent fail-ratio.

```
<?php

  $probability = 90;

  $fails = 0;
  $succeeds = 0;

  for($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++) {
    $rand = rand(1, 100);

    if ($rand <= $probability) {
      $succeeds++;
    }
    else {
      $fails++;
    }
  }

  echo 'Fail ratio: ' . ($fails / $succeeds) * 100 . ' %';

?>
```